# Impossible to get CKEDITOR instances in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, ckeditor

Let's say I have a page with an iframe and within the iframe I have some ckeditor inline instances that I want to manage from the containing page.

From the parent, if I run

```
console.log(document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.CKEDITOR);
```

I have the CKEDITOR object, but don't know why, if I run

```
console.log(document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.CKEDITOR.instances);
```

i get an "undefined" result.

Any idea?

POST EDIT: if I run the last console.log directly in the inspector I get all the instances as normal, the problem seems to exist only in the parent page js.